# ¿Cómo funciona el llenado de tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dudas de cuando intento llenar una tabla que tiene una FK de otra cómo puedo hacer si la otra yo registro varios datos y quiero que esos mismos datos esten presentes en la tabla padre como parte del registro y cómo insertar varios registros a la vez a una tabla.
html:

```js
    $(function(){
    // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
    $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
     $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");
    });
    
    // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
     var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
     $(parent).remove();
    });
    
    
    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_SE.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_form.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleUser.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="text/x-icon" href="U.png">
   <script src="fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <header>
       <div class="salida">
        <a class="outlogin" href="cerrarSession.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
     <p>Salir</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <p>Publicaciones De Los Eventos De UNERG</p>
    </div>
    <div class="regresar">
        <a class="atras" href="sistemaUsuario.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
     <p>Regresar</p>
    </div>
   </header>
   
   
   <div class="main">
        <div class="formularioEventos">
           <form action="formEvento.php" name="formulario" method="POST" id="formularioEvento">
            <h2>Publicacion De Evento</h2>
      
            <label for="title">Titulo Del Evento:</label>
            <input name="eventoTitulo" class="eventoTitulo" type="text"  id="title" placeholder="Ingrese El Titulo Del Evento">
      
      
         <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
            <input name="fechaEvento" class="fechaEvento" type="text"  id="fecha" placeholder="Ingrese La Fecha Que Se Realizara El Evento">
      
         <label for="tiempo">Tiempo:</label>
            <input name="tiempoEvento" class="tiempoEvento" type="text"  id="tiempo" placeholder="Ingrese El Tiempo Que Durara El Evento">
      
         <label for="lugar">Lugar:</label>
            <input name="lugarEvento" class="lugarEvento" type="text"  id="lugar" placeholder="Ingrese El Lugar Donde Se Realizara El Evento">
      
      <label for="contenido">Contenido:</label>
         <textarea name="contenidoEvento" class="contenidoEvento" id="contenido" placeholder="Escriba Todo A Su Gusto Acerca Del Evento"></textarea>

 
    <h3 >Agregar Ponentes </h3>
    <table class="table bg-info"  id="tabla">
     <tr class="fila-fija">
      <td><input  name="CI[]" placeholder="Cedula Del  Ponente"/></td>
      <td><input  name="nombrePonente[]" placeholder="Nombre Del Ponente"/></td>
      <td><input  name="apellidoPonente[]" placeholder="Apellido Del Ponente"/></td>
      <td class="eliminar"><input type="button"   value="Menos -"/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
     <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning"> Más + </button>
                     <h2>Tema</h2>
      
            <label for="title">Titulo Del Evento:</label>
            <input name="tema" class="eventoTitulo" type="text"  id="title" placeholder="Ingrese El Tema Del Evento">
      
      
      <input name="btnEnviar" class="enviar" id="btn" type="submit" value="Publicar">
   </form>
          </div>
   </div>
   <footer>
       <div class="pie"> 
           <p>copyright UNERG 2018 / Decoration AzX</p>
    </div>
   </footer>
   <script src="scriptEvento.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

PHP:

```
//obtenemos los valores del formulario
 if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){

     include("connect_bd.php");

     //obtenemos los valores de los formulario
     $titulo = $_POST [ 'eventoTitulo' ];
     $fecha = $_POST [ 'fechaEvento' ];
     $tiempo = $_POST [ 'tiempoEvento' ];
     $lugar = $_POST [ 'lugarEvento' ];
     $contenido = $_POST [ 'contenidoEvento' ];
     //---------------------------------------------------
     $tema = $_POST [ 'tema' ];
     //--------------------------------------------------

     $dates1 = $_POST [ 'CI' ];
     $dates2 = $_POST [ 'nombrePonente' ];
     $dates3 = $_POST [ 'apellidoPonente' ];
     //-----------------------------------------------------
     $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] = 0;
    //--------------------------------------------------------

      if($CI=="" || $nombreP==""||$apellidoP==""){       
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] = 1; 
      }else{
          $date1=current($dates1);
          $date2=current($dates2);
          $date3=current($dates3);

                $CI=(( $date1 !== false) ? $date1 : ", &nbsp;");
                $nom=(( $date2 !== false) ? $date2 : ", &nbsp;");
                $ape=(( $item3 !== false) ? $date3 : ", &nbsp;");

                $valores='('.$CI.',"'.$nom.'","'.$ape.'"),';
                $valoresQ= substr($valores, 0, -1);
          $link="INSERT INTO $tablaPonentes(ci,nombre,apellido)values $valoresQ";

        $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] = 2;

       }

      if($tema==""){         
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] =3;  
       }else{
          $link->query("INSERT INTO $tablaTemas(titulo_tema,id_ponentes)values('$tema','$link->insert_id')");
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] = 4;
      }

      if($titulo=="" ||$fecha==""||$tiempo=="" ||$lugar==""){        
          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] = 5;      
     }else{

          $link->query("INSERT INTO $tablaEvento(titulo,fecha,tiempo,lugar,contenido,id_temas)values('$titulo','$fecha','$tiempo','$lugar','$contenido','$link->insert_id')");

          $_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] =6;

      }
     include("cierre_Session.php");
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 1){
     echo'<script>alert("Faltan Campos Por Rellenar");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 2){
      echo'<script>alert("Evento Cargado Exitosamente");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 3){
     echo'<script>alert("Faltan Campos Por Rellenar");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 4){
      echo'<script>alert("Evento Cargado Exitosamente");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 5){
     echo'<script>alert("Faltan Campos Por Rellenar");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
  if($_registro['REGISTRO_EXITO'] == 6){
      echo'<script>alert("Evento Cargado Exitosamente");location.href="eventosPublicacion.html";</script>';
   }
?>
```

La parte de los ponentes no logro que la base de datos reciba los datos eso es php7 con el xampp y estoy seguro que es el tipo de inserción a la base de datos y no he encontrado nada que se parezca a la nueva que usa php. esa es la forma que mas eh visto de insertar varios registro a la tabla a la vez

Aquí la foto de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí mi duda con respecto a la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Si quieres hacer `inserts` en distintas tablas "a la vez" te recomiendo que investigues sobre las transacciones de SQL.

Comment: necesitas insertar varios registros a la vez en las 2 tablas o solo en una?

Comment: Buenas, ¿qué has intentado?, ¿podrías poner el código que tienes al respecto?

Comment: hola, eh intentado tantos códigos de diferentes tutoriales que ya ni se cual usar, estoy haciendo un sistema  de asistencia de eventos,y deseo llenar en una tabla las personas que expondrán con sus nombres y apellidos en una tabla llamada "ponentes" a una tabla llamada "temas" que serán varios para ese evento que esa misma tabla estará en una tabla llamada "eventos".la secuencia de las tablas es ponentes->temas->eventos.lo que estuve observando es que si se registran varios temas y varios ponentes en un registro como hacer que la tabla padre osea eventos tenga y  muestre todos esa información.

Comment: y que también estoy intentando llenar varios registro a la vez a la tabla ponentes pero no me funciona e intentado de todas las formas y la base de datos no me recibe los datos, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: ¡Estás en el sitio correcto!. Te recomiendo que de todos los códigos que has intentando te quedes con el que creas que es mejor, o con el que creas que entiendes más. Partiendo de ese código aquí se te puede ayudar, pero para ello es necesario que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170642/edit), y pongas el código con que hayas decidido quedarte. A partir de esa base se podrá revisar,  corregir... hasta que lo hagamos funcionar. Pero debes ser claro en el planteamiento del problema e indicar si es posible los errores que estás teniendo.

Comment: no voten por cerrar la pregunta, el usuario @A.Cedano ya le comento que debe añadir el código necesario para ayudarle, es una buena pregunta solo que sin estructura

Comment: Intenta no explicar lo que as intentado en los comentarios, es difícil de leer, por favor edita tu pregunta para añadirle todo lo necesario y darle un formato correcto.

Comment: ya esta, acabo de poner todo lo que tengo en duda

Comment: @AZX Respecto a la dudade la base de datos, debes insertar una fila por cada id_tema que quieras añadir, segun veo es una relacion 1:N, es decir un registro en temas, puede estar relacionado con N registros en eventos, pero un evento solo puede estar relacionado con un registro en la tabla temas.

Comment: La pregunta es totalmente confusa, ya que no se si hay 1, 2 o 3 preguntas en una sola. Por lo pronto, el query ultimo de ejemplo esta perfecto y muestra lo que pedis. No sabes hacer un join no? Creo que hay conceptos que tenes que revisar antes....

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se observa del código del formulario que pones en tu pregunta y de la imagen de las tablas de la base de datos es que tienes un error de diseño de la base de datos.

Analicemos pues los requerimientos, sin entrar en detalles, que se deprenden del formulario html que muestras y la base de datos.

### Requerimiento básico

1. Los **usuarios** puede publicar eventos.
2. Los **eventos** pueden tener multiples ponentes.
3. Un **ponentes** participar en un evento.
4. Un usuario consta de nombre, apellidos, mail, alias, password y rol.
5. Un evento consta de titulo, fecha, tiempo, lugar, contenido, tema y ponentes.
6. Un ponente consta de ci, nombre y apellidos.

Claramente de estas premisas podemos extraer 3 entiades (usuarios, eventos, ponentes), algunos atributos y algunas relaciones.

### Relaciones

- usuarios-eventos (1:N), un usuario multiples eventos
- eventos-usuarios (N:1), un evento solo puede ser creado por un usuario
- eventos-ponentes (1:N), un evento multiples ponentes
- ponentes-eventos (N:1), un ponente un evento

### Tablas y atributos

> usuarios

- id
- nombre
- apellidos
- mail
- alias (usuario en tu tabla)
- password
- rol (passwordAdmin en tu tabla)

> eventos

- id
- id_usuario (FK tabla usuarios)
- titulo
- fecha
- tiempo
- lugar
- contenido
- tema (solo es otro atributo, no una tabla aparte)

> ponentes

- id
- id_evento (FK tabla eventos)
- ci
- nombre
- apellidos

---

Con esta estructura a la hora de crear un evento haremos **1+N** consultas insert a la base de datos, es decir 1 consulta insert a la tabla eventos y (N) tantas como ponentes tenga un evento a la tabla ponentes.

Vayamos al codigo php:

```
<?php
 //obtenemos los valores del formulario
 if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){
    include("connect_bd.php");

    // DATOS EVENTO
    $titulo    = $_POST['eventoTitulo'];
    $fecha     = $_POST['fechaEvento'];
    $tiempo    = $_POST['tiempoEvento'];
    $lugar     = $_POST['lugarEvento'];
    $contenido = $_POST['contenidoEvento'];
    $tema      = $_POST['tema'];

    // DATOS PONENTES
    // seran arrays con los datos
    $cis              = $_POST [ 'CI' ];
    $nombrePonentes   = $_POST [ 'nombrePonente' ];
    $apellidoPonentes = $_POST [ 'apellidoPonente' ];

    // INSERTAR EVENTO
    // preparamos la consulta
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO eventos (titulo, fecha, tiempo, lugar, contenido, tema) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        /* Ligar parámetros para marcadores */
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $titulo, $fecha, $tiempo, $lugar, $contenido, $tema);

        /* Ejecutar la consulta */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* Obtener el id de la ultima insercion */
        $id_evento = mysqli->insert_id
    }

    // INSERTAR PONENTES
    // preparamos la consulta
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO ponentes (id_evento, ci, nombre, apellidos) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        // recorremos y insertamos los ponentes
        foreach($nombrePonentes as $k => $ponente) {
            /* Ligar parámetros para marcadores */
            $stmt->bind_param("isss", $id_evento, $cis[$k], $nombrePonentes[$k], $apellidoPonentes[$K]);
            /* Ejecutar la consulta */
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: la verdad no se que es lo que pasa, hize los pasos que dijistes pero cuando le doy registrar la pantalla se carga en blanco y la base de datos no tiene nada

Comment: bueno vi que tenia mal escrita la tabla la acomode hize que mostrara un mensaje de: "datos ingresado con exito" pero la base de datos sigue igual de vacia